# HTML 4.01 Validation double quotation marks issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I'm trying to validate successfully an html page with elements created dynamically but I get the following error from the HTML 4.01 Strict validator:

> ".." is not a member of a group specified for any attribute

Referring to the two dots in the url specified as background:

```
<div onclick="startGame();" style="background: url("../media/backgrounds/lev0.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;" id="gamewindow"></div>
```

Apparently the validator thinks the " after url( to be the end of the style attribute and in such manner gives me the error and two following still related to this issue.
The main problem is that the inline style attribute is defined via javascript and I cannot change the double quotation marks to a single ' since it is done in automatic. I modified the code in the Direct Input field of the validator replacing " with ' and it worked well without any errors. 
Any ideas of how to solve this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How the style attribute being define by javascript?  With jquery?  With `.setAttribute()`?  With `element.style.background`?

Comment: Still broken. The attribute is being defined with Javascript:
 document.getElementById("gamewindow").style.background = "url(../media/backgrounds/lev0.png)";

Comment: How do you test the HTML dynamically created with that code? And did the code actually work? If so, HTML should be actually valid, probably you checked it incorrectly. Firefox reports the value of such dynamically added attribute as `style="background: url(&quot;/img/logo.png&quot;) ..."`, which is completely valid.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I was using a bookmarklet I wrote to get the dynamically generated HTML:
javascript:x=document.body.innerHTML.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/\n/g,'<br>'); document.body.innerHTML = "&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" <br> \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"> <br>&lt;html> <br> &lt;head> <br>&lt;meta http-equiv = \"Content-Type\" content = \"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"> <br>&lt;title>dynamic code&lt;/title> <br>&lt;/head> <br>&lt;body>" + x + "  <br>&lt;/body><br>&lt;/html>";

Comment: And what is `x` in this code: simply result of string contacenation or something like `document.body.innerHTML`? I'd suggest using the latter, since it corresponds to the actual DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using setAttribute method:

```
document.getElementById("gamewindow").setAttribute('style',"background:url('../media/backgrounds/lev0.png')");
```

In such way the single ' containing the url are translated back to CSS as such and not as " as done by using the .style property.